# Create CSC call from Visual Studio config

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, build-automation

I feel like this is a question that's likely to have been answered already, but I'm having trouble finding it. Chalk it up to bad search terms, perhaps.

I've been working in Visual Studio 2005 Professional for about a month now, and thus far I've been using the built-in compile mechanism with mostly-default settings (the only thing I've changed with any real frequency is the build path). I'd like, however, to move to using more automated build techniques. To that end, I'd like to switch to using `csc` calls instead of hitting `Ctrl-Shift-B` or `F5`, so that I can include the lines in build scripts and other tools (like NAnt).

My question is, does Visual Studio or any third party tool provide a way to programmatically convert the compile setting ins VS to its `csc` equivalent? For example, if I have a project called SampleProject with the `Output type:` field set to Windows Application, it would look something like:

```
csc /output:winexe /target:SampleProject.exe *.cs
```

I know it's usually not terribly difficult to work this out by hand, but if there's a way to automatically pull it together, it's that much better.

Comment: Research MSBUILD. Also, say which version and which edition of Visual Studio you're using. For instance, Visual Studio 2010 Professional?

Comment: @John Thanks for the suggestions - I'll start reading about MSBuild now. I'm using VS2005 Pro, and I updated the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on VS2010, but similar should work for other versions:

Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run

Change the "MSBuild project build output verbosity" to "Normal" (or higher)

Build, and bring up the Output window (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>).

Change the "Show output from" drop-down to "Build"

You should see an indicative `csc` line. Note this is ***not*** truly what it executed; it is a happy lie. IIRC it actually executes directly, and there are some corner-cases where what it outputs there is not *quite* the same as what you would need.

Comment: I tested this, and it's as you said. But there are some things that surprised me, like: `/reference:c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll` - I would have expected things like this to be things CSC would automatically know about, and not need a reference provided.

Comment: @kaldrenon and you aren't wrong ;p Actually, though, in later versions this is handy, because you might be using the C# 4.0 compiler, but targetting .NET 2.0, so you still need to tell csc which version of System.dll to use. Not an issue in VS2005 though - you can drop those, and it will indeed use defaults (unless you disable them)